# How soon could the UK see a general election?

Tags: united-kingdom, election

Bearing in mind that the Fixed Term act was repealed, what can the Commons do to trigger a general election? Would enough light blue moderates agree with the opposition to pass a parliamentary motion of no confidence?

Comment: Traditionally, civil unrest or general strikes occurred when a government was really, really unpopular in a democracy in the past. Is it that bad already in the UK?

Comment: Are you asking a factual question about how an election is called, or looking for speculation on how Truss might be removed?

Comment: I think this question might be more helpful for future readers if it was reformulated to be a more general 'How may general elections be called post-repeal of the FTPA' canonical question - I don't think we have one of those on the site at the moment.

Comment: I removed all the personal opinion and commentary on the current political climate so we can focus on the actual on-topic procedural question.

Comment: This seem to be asking for speculation on a future event, and is, as such, unknowable.  So I've voted to close.

Answer (score 20):

The Guardian has just published an explainer covering this question:

https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2022/oct/17/routes-towards-general-election-uk-explainer-liz-truss

Basically, the options seem to be:

- Liz Truss calls for elections out of her own volition
- She is replaced as Tory leader and her successor calls for elections (the Guardian article argues that the successor would be under even greater pressure to do so, being a non-elected prime minister following on another non-elected prime minister)
- She loses a vote of confidence (either a formal one and it is automatic, or eg a budget vote, and she ought to go for it)
- Or she actually stays on for 2 years

None of the options seem to work without participation of either Truss herself, or a significant number of Tory MPs.

Comment: All of this assumes the King acts only on the advice of the PM. This is not a legal certainty. For example, the PM may try to avoid a confidence vote by pro-rogueing Parliament. In an extreme example, the King could call an election or appoint another PM.

Comment: seeing as this is politics se it's worth noting that given the way polls are at the moment the Tory party wants to avoid a GE at almost any cost. They'd only call one if they thought that the longterm damage of _not_ calling one would outweigh the catastrophic result they'd suffer. My money's on 2 years, with or without LT as PM

Comment: @Scott: the British constitution is all about convention - i.e. theory vs practice. So while you may be correct in theory, in practice the King acts only on the "advice" of his government, and takes no action unless so advised. Also, after what Boris tried, a PM proroguing Parliament to avoid...discomfort would, at best, have very bad optics. For a PM as weak as this one, I don't see that as a realistic possibility.

Comment: @Scott and *this* King is rather new to the game, and hasn't established himself as a stabilising influence. There's a very real possibility that if he were politically active, he'd be the *last* King.

Comment: Dissolving Parliament is a bit different from other Royal Prerogative powers: the Prime Minister is not allowed to "advise" the Monarch to dissolve Parliament, only to "request" a dissolution.  There's a set of criteria called the Lascelles Principles for when the Monarch is allowed to refuse the PM's request.  At a pinch, I suppose one could assert that if the opposite conditions from those in the Lascelles Principles are met, the Monarch can proceed with a dissolution without a request from the PM.  But I don't think we're in that much of a pinch yet.

Comment: I've already said this on another platform, but a Commons vote of no confidence may not be enough, because of this clause in the 2011 Cabinet Manual: 'The Prime Minister is expected to resign where it is clear that he or she does not have the confidence of the House of Commons _and that an alternative government does have the confidence._' (my italics)  A PM who loses a VONC might refuse either to request a dissolution or to resign, claiming that the second condition is not met.

Comment: @DanielHatton The two conditions only applies to resignation. If they're not met, then dissolution and an election is the expected outcome. Even if they are met, the PM can still choose to request a dissolution anyway.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Yes, a dissolution and an election _ought_ to be the expected outcome when neither the incumbent PM nor anyone else has confidence.  But if the incumbent PM is determined not to request a dissolution, then how does one get that dissolution?  Presumably one has to appoint a new PM who doesn't initially have confidence, but who will request a dissolution in an attempt to get confidence, as happened in 1852.  I think a repeat of that 1852 solution is rendered impossible by the wording in the Cabinet Manual.